# Random duplicate content bug with Bootstrap popovers and FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, popover

**Note: I understand there's a bug in bootstrap that causes popovers/tooltips to call the `content function()` twice, but I do not think that is the case here.**

I am using bootstrap popovers in conjunction with the FullCalendar gem to update events.

Inside the popover, there're multiple divs that get hidden/shown depending on which view the user is on (i.e. there is a view for displaying the event info and another for updating the view). The way I'm handling this is by using `addClass('hide')` and `removeClass('hide')`, so correct me if this is improper.

When I click on an event, it displays the popover with the content added it to once (good). When I navigate to the update `div` inside the popover and send an `.ajax({type: 'PUT'})`, the popover for the updated event displays two of the content `div`s (bad); however, this happens **randomly**.

If I reload the entire DOM and redo the process over and over again, this duplication happens ~half the time.

When popover is clicked just after DOM loads (good)

[image: before updating]

When popover is clicked after `ajax PUT` is called, this **SOMETIMES HAPPENS** (even if no fields are changed)

[image: after updating]

Here's how I send the .ajax request:

```
  // SAVE button for LESSONS, POPOVER ***/
  $('body').on('click', 'button.popover-lesson-save', function() {

    var title = $('.popover input.popover-lesson-title').val();
    var note = $('.popover input.popover-lesson-note').val();

    // Retrieve event data from popover
    var idStr = $('.popover div.popover-body').data('id');
    var id = parseInt(idStr);

    // Store event data into a hash for AJAX request and refetches events
    var data = {
      title: title,
      note: note
    };

    // Make PUT AJAX request to database
    $.ajax({
      url: '/lessons/' + id,
      type: 'PUT',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',

      success: function(resp){
        $('.popover div.popover-lessons-edit').addClass('hide');
        $('.popover div.popover-lessons-view').removeClass('hide');
        $('.popover').popover('hide');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
      },
      error: function(resp){
        alert('Error code 2-502-1. Oops, something went wrong.');
      }

    });
  });
```

And here is what I do in my FullCalendar callbacks:

```
  // calendar options
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ..
    eventRender: function(calEvent, element, view){

        if (typeof $(element).data('bs.popover') === 'undefined'){
          // Find content html (append and clone prevents parent div from being overwritten)
          var content = $("<div />").append($('.popover-lessons-content').clone());
          var id = calEvent.id;

          // Attach popover to html element
          $(element).popover({
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'left',
            html: true,
            content: function(){
              return content.html(); // This randomly duplicates
            }
          });
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @c-smile, I've realised that the bug lied in how I retrieve my html template from my view file:

```
var content = $("<div />").append($('.popover-lessons-content').clone());
```

Instead, I should have done this (and this worked after much tinkering):

```
      var content = $('.popover-lessons-content').html();

      $(element).popover({
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'left',
        html: true,
        content: function(){
          return content;
        }
      });
```

It takes the direct html instead of cloning the div and making a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me that instead of `append()` here

```
var content = $("<div />").append($('.popover-lessons-content').clone());
```

you should use `appendTo()`. And yet not sure about purpose of `clone()` so I think it should look like as:

```
var content = $("<div />").appendTo('.popover-lessons-content');
```

and to avoid duplicates that $('.popover-lessons-content') thing should be cleared before appending to it.

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem to be working, but if I may clarify, the `div` with class `.popover-lessons-content` is a hidden html template for the popover. Running just `$("<div />").appendTo('.popover-lessons-content');` in the console gave me an empty `[<div></div>]`. I've figured it out though, thanks to your comment about the usage of .append() and .clone()